# PayPal, IPNs for Xenforo and Buttons

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, xenforo

I have to figure out what I need to do to sort out a couple of IPN problems I have created.
Here's what I have:
- One PayPal account
- PayPal Buttons that do not require IPNs
- 2 Xenforo forums which have paid user upgrades activated

I have activated IPN under Notifications for the Xenforo site that is active. The second site is not used much and with only one IPN, that means it gets an error. This is not my first concern right now.

My buttons get used, and also through IPN errors. I see I can override the notify_url in the advanced settings, but I don't have an url to use. I don't need an url notified for these purchases. Is there something I can put in there to overide the xenforo notify_url or simply cause the button to not notify any url?

How can I deal with two xenforo sites when I am only allowed one PayPal account?

Thanks for explaining my options

Answer (score 0):

Any transaction can specify its own notify_url at transaction setup/creation/redirect time , which will override any setting in the PayPal account.

The Notify URL in the PayPal account is just the default one that will be used if none is given at transaction time.

---

Ensure that any URL you give responds with an HTTP 200 OK/success status, since if it does not respond with a 2xx status, PayPal will consider the delivery failed and will keep retrying and will eventually deactivate the IPN delivery service for your account.